# Cakephp only showing one record out of four records in the database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have looped through my record, when i use print_r(), i will see all my records, but if i try to display it in a table, it will only show one record.

Please how do i solve this?

```
<?php foreach ($clists as $clist) ;?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $clist['Course']['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($clist['Course']['course_name'], array('controller' => 'this', 'action' => 'this')); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $clist['Course']['course_desc']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $clist['Course']['closing_day']; ?></td>
</tr> <?php //endforeach; ?> <?php unset($clist); ?> –
}
```

Comment: You need to modify your code so that it works properly.

Comment: How do you loop through it?

Comment: <?php foreach($clists as $clist);?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $clist['Course']['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $this->Html->link($clist['Course']['course_name'],
array('controller'=>'this','action'=>'this')
) ;?></td>
<td><?php echo $clist['Course']['course_desc']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $clist['Course']['closing_day']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php //endforeach; ?>
<?php unset($clist); ?>

Comment: You unset your array in the foreach loop. Set the unset outside of it

Answer (score 0):

How do you loop through your array?

Here is a great example on how to echo the results in an array:

```
<?php 
//Example array
$colors = array(
   "red", 
   "green", 
   "blue", 
   "yellow"
); 

foreach ($colors as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}
?>
```

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Also, for example;

```
$result = array(
  [0] => 'DB result 1',
  [1] => 'DB result 2',
  [2] => 'DB result 3'
);
```

To show these results in a table for example in this case would be:

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($result as $key => $value) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $value ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } // End foreach ?>
</table>
```

Good luck!

Comment: I did the same thing, look at my code below<?php foreach($clists as $clist);?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $clist['Course']['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $this->Html->link($clist['Course']['course_name'],
array('controller'=>'this','action'=>'this')
) ;?></td>
<td><?php echo $clist['Course']['course_desc']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $clist['Course']['closing_day']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php //endforeach; ?>
<?php unset($clist); ?>

Comment: You unset your array in the foreach loop. Set the unset outside of it